# What does "being in hell" mean in this title?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I read an article titled ["Working with Bill Gates Was Like 'Being in Hell,' Allen Says"](http://www.newsfactor.com/news/Working-with-Gates-Like--Being-in-Hell-/story.xhtml?story_id=10200BKSLT4O) and I don't understand what "being in hell" means. There are two meanings in my opinion.

1. When he worked with Gates, it was like working in Hell.
2. When he worked with Gates, he worked very hard.

What's the real meaning of "being in hell" here?

Comment: Why I got down-vote for this question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This uses *hell* in its meaning of “a state or place of great suffering; an unbearable experience”. Examples include: *I've been through hell*; *he made her life hell*.

So it means it was a harsh and unpleasant employment.